# ANTLR Grammar is not backtracking while parsing similar rules

Tags: antlr, grammar, ambiguity, backtracking

Suppose I have a grammar which takes care of the global variables and some method declarations of some variation of C

```
program: (declaration)* (procedure)*;
declaration: typespec identifier ';';
procedure: typespec identifier '(' ')' ';';
typespec: 'char' | 'int';
identifier: ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z') ('A' - 'Z' | 'a' .. 'z' | '0' .. '9' | '_')*;
```

If I feed it something like:

```
int MAX;
char proc();
```

the grammar reads int MAX; correctly but then it wants to apply the declaration rule also to the 2nd row, and it fails when it reaches (, and at this point I expect it to backtrack and apply the next rule which is the one for procedure. Could somebody please tell me why this isn't happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you post all of your grammar?  I couldn't get it to compile as you posted...but I played around with what you posted to make it match your example:

```
program: (declaration)* (procedure)*;
statement: TYPE_SPEC IDENT ;
declaration: statement ';';
procedure: statement '(' ')' ';';

TYPE_SPEC 
    :   'char' | 'int';

IDENT 
    :   ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z') ('A' .. 'Z' | 'a' .. 'z' | '0' .. '9' | '_')*;

WHITESPACE
    :   ('\r' | '\n' | '\r\n' | ' ' | '\t' ) {$channel=HIDDEN;} 
    ;
```

I'd recommend that your make lexer rules (The ones in capitals) for your token matching rather than making them part of your parser rules - I've done some of them already for you as you can see.

Comment: That wasn't the whole grammar, I just isolated an example. I tried to run your grammar and I got the following (<grammar SimpleC> (program NoViableAltException(6@[()* loopback of 2:10: ( declaration )*])))

Comment: What input did you enter when you tested?

Comment: The one that was up above. The thing is that I ran it with the interpretor, and I got that error. If I create the actual lexer and parser with Tool it works. I think I've been fooled all day by the interpretor:|